# Failed to add a TIFF file as a raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster

I am new to QGIS. The system of my computer is 32-bit operating system, with x64-based processor. My QGIS version is 3.12.1. The TIFF file that I am using is 322 MB large. But every time when I add this file as a raster layer, my QGIS cannot load it. The status bar at the bottom is always loading. The task manager of my computer shows that the QGIS software is using 99% of CPU. I don't know how to solve this problem. I have tried some samples of TIFF files on internet, and they works.

Actually, I successfully opened the TIFF file (the 322MB one) once. It was when I first downloaded it on a website. But later, I could not open it via QGIS anymore.

Comment: did you try to download the file again?

Comment: May be try to build pyramids of your raster? You will find the processing "Build overviews pyramids" in the processing toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T)

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn tried

Comment: @Christophe let me try

Comment: Run gdalinfo for your image and include the report into your question.